# How to catch exit() in embedded C++ module from python code?

Tags: python, exception, binding, exit

I am embedding a c++ library (binding done with SIP) in my python application. Under certain circonstances (error cases), this library uses exit(), which causes my entire application to exit. 
Is there a way to catch this event, or do I need to modify the library to handle error cases differently ?

Thank you very much,

Comment: exit()? In a library? Somebody needs to be spanked.

Comment: FWIW: The Google test library apparently has implemented a means of circumventing exit() calls. In unit tests, you can test for program exit using the `ASSERT_EXIT` macro. See [gtest Advanced Guide](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/AdvancedGuide)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must modify the source of the library. There is no "exception handling" in C and `exit()` does not return to the calling code under any circumstances.

Comment: +1.  For some cases `atexit()` may help, but not if one needs to return to the calling code.

Comment: Thank you, no I am sure of what I have to do ! 
Rgds,

Answer (score 0):

You can override the library linking with LD_LIBRARY_PATH and make your own exit function.  Works fine.